# asserting Alt attribute of all images on webpage with protractor

Tags: javascript, protractor

i am new to protractor and need some help. i have a scenario where i need to assert that all images should have alt attribute (no matter what text or empty) on a web page. i tired the following :

1) **expect(element(by.css(a.brand-logo img.img-responsive))).toBe(true);**

2) **expect(element(by.css(img[src="/1.5.19.0-SNAPSHOT/assets/cp-logo-small.png"]))).toBe(true);**

when i run the above two assertions they both are passing, but i want first to be pass and second to be fail as there is no alt attribute.

Answer (score 0):

> the above two assertions they both are passing,

These assertions don't make much sense at all, since you are *expecting an element to be true*. You've probably meant to use [`isPresent()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementFinder.prototype.isPresent) instead:

```
expect(elm.isPresent()).toBe(true);
```

---

To get the `alt` attribute use [`getAttribute()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.getAttribute):

```
var logo = $("img[itemprop=logo]");
expect(logo.getAttribute("alt")).toEqual("CHI");
```

If you want to check the absence of an `alt` attribute, use `toBeDefined()`:

```
expect(logo.getAttribute("alt")).toBeDefined();
```

Comment: var elm = element(by.css(a.brand-logo img.img-responsive)).getAttribute('alt');                             expect(elm.isPresent()).toBe(true); //is this what you want me to do.

Comment: @Peter call `getAttribute("alt")` on both of your elements and use `toBeDefined()` check.

Comment: Thanks alecxe, i have tried "expect(logo.getAttribute("alt")).toBeDefined();" but the result is same its passing for both assertions with and without alt attribute. is there any other alternative

Comment: @Peter okay, let's first log what we've got. Use: `logo.getAttribute("alt").then(function (value) { console.log(value) });`. What is printed on the console?

Comment: hi alecxe, its printing for the text under alt attribute for the first img tag with alt attribute and not printing anything for the second img tag without alt attribute.